# Swift Image open animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I would like to do following fullscreen image animation in Swift. The fullscreen image opening animation on click of an item.

https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/692322/screenshots/3731362/dribbble.gif

Can you help me and suggest how to get this done?

Comment: Are your images put in collection view. If I am correct then you want to add the animation similar to app opening animation in iPhone. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: yes, images are in collectionview.
Yes, i want to do animation similar to app opening animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you have to use custom **UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning**.

Create a class **AnimateTransition**

```
import UIKit

enum TransitionType {
    case Presenting, Dismissing
}

class AnimateTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
   var duration: TimeInterval
   var isPresenting: Bool
   var originFrame: CGRect
   var collectionView: UICollectionView
   init(withDuration duration: TimeInterval, forTransitionType type: TransitionType, originFrame: CGRect, collectionView: UICollectionView) {
    self.duration = duration
    self.isPresenting = type == .Presenting
    self.originFrame = originFrame
    self.collectionView = collectionView
    super.init()
}

func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return self.duration
}

func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    var selected: IndexPath?
    if collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.count == 0 {
        selected = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    }
    else {
        selected = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?[0]
    }
    print("Selected cell: \(String(describing: selected?.row))")
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: selected!)
    let container: UIView? = transitionContext.containerView
    let fromVC: UIViewController? = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)
    let toVC: UIViewController? = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)
    let fromView: UIView? = fromVC?.view
    let toView: UIView? = toVC?.view
    let beginFrame: CGRect? = container?.convert((cell?.contentView.bounds)!, from: cell?.contentView)
    var endFrame: CGRect = transitionContext.initialFrame(for: fromVC!)
    endFrame = toView?.frame ?? CGRect.zero
    var move: UIView? = nil
    var transitionDuration: CGFloat
    if isPresenting {
        transitionDuration = CGFloat(self.duration)
        toView?.frame = endFrame
        move = toView?.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
        move?.frame = beginFrame!
        cell?.isHidden = true
    }
    else {
        transitionDuration =  CGFloat(self.duration)
        move = cell?.contentView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
        move?.frame = (fromView?.frame)!
        fromView?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    container?.addSubview(move!)
    if isPresenting {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(transitionDuration) , animations: {() -> Void in
            move?.frame = endFrame
        }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
            move?.removeFromSuperview()
            toView?.frame = endFrame
            container?.addSubview(toView!)
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })
    }
    else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(transitionDuration) , delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 20, initialSpringVelocity: 15, options: [], animations: {() -> Void in
            move?.frame = beginFrame!
        }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
            cell?.isHidden = false
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
        })
    }
}
 }
```

Then in your viewController perform a model transition like

```
    cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    vc.transitioningDelegate = self
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Then add these delegates in viewController class

```
func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return AnimateTransition(withDuration: 0.5, forTransitionType: .Dismissing, originFrame: (self.cell?.frame)!, collectionView: collectionView)
}

func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController,
                         presenting: UIViewController,
                         source: UIViewController)
    -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? { 
    return AnimateTransition(withDuration: 0.5, forTransitionType: .Presenting, originFrame: (self.cell?.frame)!, collectionView: collectionView)
}
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: Rahul:

Thanks for answer, it worked.

I want to animate the other items of the second view controller as well
Any idea how to do that?

Comment: You can use CAAnimation for that.

Comment: yes, I used that, but I want both animation to happen together.
Image opening fullscreen and animation inside the new viewcontroller

Comment: can you please give me a example how the animation should be using some gifs.

Comment: I want animation exactly like this:
https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/692322/screenshots/3731362/dribbble.gif

When image opens fullscreen, the top bar slides up and disappears
The new viewcontrollers top bar slides in from right and bottom panel slides up inside.

All these animations happen together.

Comment: Hey, how to do same animation on viewcontroller dismiss?

Comment: On Dismissing the viewcontroller, the new viewcontroller simply disappears

Comment: Please check whether func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? is getting called

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CATransform3DMakeScale` for making scale in your transform animation action.